# No effect on button click in multithreaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Everything works except the stop button. (Button 3 and button 4 OnClick):

I have made an application which has four buttons.

It is a multi-threaded application.

Button 1 and 2 will start spawning threads.

Button 3 and 4 will stop that process respectively.

But it does not seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Action act = () => textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
                    textBox1.Invoke(act);
                }
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                } 
            }
        }, token);
        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //token.Cancel();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Action act = () => textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
                    textBox2.Invoke(act);
                }
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                } 
            }
        }, token);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //token.Cancel();
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here's the updated code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultiThreading_Start_Stop_Counter
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token;
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        token1 = cancellationTokenSource1.Token;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                // your code
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Action act = () => textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
                textBox1.Invoke(act);
            }
        });
        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (token1.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    token1.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                // your code
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Action act = () => textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
                textBox2.Invoke(act);
            }
        });
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource1.Cancel();
    }
}
}
```

Now the task is cancelling but with this exception:

*An exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The operation was canceled.*

Solved:

used while loop. Thank you!

Comment: Do you get an error? Also instead of while (true) do something like while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of checking if the token is cancelled should be placed inside the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
     }
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     Action act = () => textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
     textBox1.Invoke(act);
}
```

Plus you throw the OperationCanceledException and do not catch it.

If you do not want to handle the exception, you can introduce some variable for while loop like:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var run = true;
            while (run)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        run = false;
                        break;
                    }
                   //loop code
                } 
            }
        }, token);
```

button2 should contain code to cancel the token *cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();*

And you need diffrent CancellationTokenSource and CancellationToken for button 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

- Cancel method belongs to CancellationTokenSource so you can't call it on CancellationToken
- if (token.IsCancellationRequested) is called only after 100 seconds, so maybe you just did not wait long enough or more probably put the check in wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as @Roman said,

You should make a new `CancellationTokenSource` for each `CancellationToken`, if token is requested in different Tasks.

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource1, cancellationTokenSource2;
CancellationToken token1, token2;
```

Make two different `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken`.

Use them in your for loop or in while loop as below, depending on your cancellation situation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (token1.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        token1.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    // your code
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Action act = () => textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
    textBox1.Invoke(act);
}
```

Or

```
while (token1.IsCancellationRequested)
{
}
```